# Check if header is present in request with IIS and the value

Tags: iis, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

How could I check if a request header exist on IIS 8 and the value of this header is for example "1234"?

I am trying to response with a 500 error for example if the header is not present or the value is not "1234" so you can´t access if you haven´t the secret value.

it is possible on IIS? I check the all availables server variables but I don´t find any reference to Request headers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-dev-reference/server-variables

Comment: Does ALL_RAW help? You may need to write regex to extract the header name and value of it though.

Comment: Thanks so much this is the variable that I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A request header is an HTTP header that can be used in an HTTP request to provide information about the request context, so I suggest you can try to use custom HTTP headers in a urlrewrite condition:

- custom headers need to be preceded by "HTTP_".
- substitute dashes with underscores

Eg: in order to retrieve the custom header "x-app-version", you can use "HTTP_x_app_version". So thr urlrewrite config should look like this:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="false">
 <match url="(.*)" />  
  <conditions>
   <add input="{HTTP_x_app_version}" pattern="^1234$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="your url" />
</rule>
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and upvote it.